# Generalizing Collect

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

`Collect` only seems to work with `Times` and `Plus`. How can we generalize `Collect` to f and g where f plays the role of `Times` and g that of `Plus` ?

To simplify the task let's consider only a custom made times:

```
ClearAll[times];
times = Diamond;
SetAttributes[Diamond,
  DeleteCases[Attributes[Times], Protected]
  ];
```

Next a function that converts an expression with `Times` and `Power` to one that has only `times`:

```
timesit[x_] := 
  x /. {Times -> times, a_^b_ :> times @@ ConstantArray[a, b]};
```

Consider an expression as a test:

```
expression = u*o + o*t + o^3*h + o^3*w;
```

Nothing changes when using `Collect`:

```
Collect[timesit[expression], o];
```

$$ h\diamond (o\diamond o\diamond o)+o\diamond t+o\diamond u+(o\diamond o\diamond o)\diamond w $$

Consider then a custom collect.

A first naive attempt could be:

```
expression //. 
 times[b : Longest[o ..], d_] + times[b : Longest[o ..], s_] :> 
  times[b, (d + s)]
```

$$ o\diamond (o\diamond o\diamond (h+w)+t+u) $$

Not what I wanted. That looks more like some sort of `HornerForm`.

This works however:

```
GatherBy[List @@ timesit@expression, 
   Count[#, o] &] /. {times[b : Longest[o ..], d_], 
    times[b : Longest[o ..], s_]} :> times[b, (d + s)] // Total
```

`o⋄(t+u)+o⋄o⋄o⋄(h+w)`

$$ o\diamond o\diamond o\diamond (h+w)+o\diamond (t+u) $$

But it uses many functions and de-structures the expression into a list. Is there a faster more elegant way ?